# Variables using Guzzle not going through (Lumen)

Tags: php, laravel-5, lumen, guzzle

I have:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class GetBlahCommand extends Command {

    protected $name = 'blah:blah';
    protected $description = "name";

    public function handle()
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $res = $client->request('GET', 'https://someapi.com', [
            'api_key' => ['privatekey']
        ]);
        echo $res->getStatusCode();
    }
}
```

But the param api_key isn't being passed along.

How can I get this to work?

---

I have adjusted my code, but now I am getting NULL returned:

```
$ndbnos = [
            'ndbno' => '01009'
        ];

        $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'https://soemapi.com']);
        $res = $client->request('GET', '/', [
            'query' => array_merge([
                'api_key' => 'somekey'
            ], $ndbnos)
        ])->getBody();
        $res = json_decode($res);

        var_dump($res);
```

---

I figured it out:

```
public function handle()
    {
        $ndbnos = [
            'ndbno' => '01009'
        ];

        $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'https://someapi.com']);
        $res = $client->request('GET', '', [
            'query' => array_merge([
                'api_key' => 'somekey',
                'format' => 'json'
            ], $ndbnos)
        ]);
        print_r(json_decode($res->getBody()));
    }
```

Comment: you pass `api-key` as `form-param`

Answer (score 0):

You can be do it by the following way:

```
public function handle()
{
    $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'https://someapi.com/']);
    $res = $client->request('GET', '/', [
    'headers' => [
            'api_key' => 'YOUR_KEY'
    ]
    ]);
}
```

I thought it's a header parameter. If it's a form input you can do it by the following way:

```
public function handle()
{
    $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'https://someapi.com/']);
    $res = $client->request('GET', '/', [
    'query' => [
            'api_key' => 'YOUR_KEY'
    ]
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the response?

Comment: if you use get method its bether to use `query` instead `form_params`,this send parameters in `url`

Comment: Thanks, Also I am change my response regarding that.